# Bad IP route after restart network

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, network-interface, iproute

I would like to make a IP route persistent, but it disappears after a reboot or service restart.

here my net conf :

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:ce:1c:48 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.56/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.255.255.24/9 brd 10.255.255.255 scope global eth0:23
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fece:1c48/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

cat ifcfg-eth0

```
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.0.0.56
NETMASK=255.255.0.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
```

cat ifcfg-eth0:23

```
ONBOOT=yes
DEVICE=eth0:23
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.255.255.24
CONNECTED_MODE=yes
NETMASK=255.128.0.0
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.128.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.128.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

When i want ping 10.128.0.1, I can't do it !
On the other hand, when i run this command :

```
ip r d 10.128.0.0/9 ; ip r a 10.128.0.0/9 via 10.0.0.1
```

i can ping my other server (10.128.0.1) and my route is corrected.

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
10.128.0.0      10.0.0.1        255.128.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

ping 10.128.0.1

```
PING 10.128.0.1 (10.128.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.128.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
64 bytes from 10.128.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
```

Yet I took the care to add the route file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

Like this :

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
10.128.0.0/9 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

I don't understand why my route is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `eth0:23` configuration.

Its address overlaps with `10.128.0.0/9` so it looks to the system as directly connected. That's why the system won't let you add a route through the default gateway!

You can see by `route -n` that the gateway is `0.0.0.0`, which means *directly connected*, so the line

```
10.128.0.0/9 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
```

cannot be execute (it probably gives an error in some log file, too).

Obviously, when you explicitly delete the route, then the system lets you add a route via the default gateway as it no more have another route (the directly connected one) in its tables.

To fix this, you have to delete the `eth0:23` interface, as 10.128.0.0/9 it's not a connected network and you shouldn't have an IP address on that machine.

Comment: Effectively, but i need IP address 10.255.255.24/9.
do you have other suggestions ?

Comment: @BlaST77 How can that IP be reached if it's not directly connected? Can you update your question sharing a bit more information on your network setup?

Comment: it's a virtual machine.
VM : 10.0.0.56/16  ; 10.255.255.24/9
Hypervisor : 10.0.0.1/16 ; 10.128.0.1/9
The network 10.0.0.0/16 is connected on a bridge.
IP 10.128.0.1 in Hypervisor is the real card

Comment: @BlaST77 well, it won't matter if it's virtual or not. If you need to go through 10.0.0.1 to reach the 10.128.0.0/9 network, your machine SHOULD NOT have an address in that network.

Comment: if I need this VM have the address 10.255.255.24
because this VM is a server and the listening IP is 10.255.255.24.
the clients of this server are in the 10.128.0.0/9 network.
You understand ?

Comment: how would you do?

Comment: @BlaST77 `10.255.255.24` IS in the same network as 10.128.0.0/9, so the clients AND the server MUST be on the SAME network and not routed through `10.0.0.1`, i.e. your server should be connected to the SAME (virtual?) switch/switches/VLANs/etc as the clients.